# How to pass the Dropdown value as parameter?

Tags: angular, firebase, ng-bootstrap

This is my drop down menu.

```
<div class="btn-group mr-3" >
                <div class="btn-group" ngbDropdown role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown" >
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbDropdownToggle>Job Type</button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" ngbDropdownMenu >
                      <button ngbDropdownItem *ngFor="let city of City" #city required>{{city}}</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

This is the button click function

```
<div class="formGroup">
                <input type="button" class="btn btnPrimary" value="Log in"
                  (click)="authuService.SignIn(useremail.value, userPassword.value, city.value)">
              </div>
```

This is not working.So how to pass the selected item value like this. Please help

Comment: An ng-bootstrap dropdown is not a form element. It doesn't have a value. It isn't design to "select" something, but just as a dropdown menu conainin buttons to click. If you want a select box in a form, use a select.

Comment: I want pass the value like this. So if i use select tag is it possible? or can you suggest Any other drop down code for this please.

Comment: No. What you want to do is use the right tool for the job. A select box is what HTML provides in order to select an element among several ones. A form is what HTML uses to gather information and submit information. And Angular has support for forms, and select boxes in forms, with validation, binding, and everything. Learn how to use forms. https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: Ok i got it. thanks a lot